# react-navigation 1.0.0-beta.7 breaking app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to build a very simple react-native app to test react-navigation. It works fine until I install react-navigation and load the following code.

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

Upon running, it gives me the message "unable to resolve module 
'react/lib/ReactComponentWithPureRenderMixin' from 'Users/me/Desktop/Code/flexbox/node_modules/react-navigation/src/views/Header.js'..." despite the file actually existing at that location when I navigate to it manually. I've tried the clearing watchman, deleting / reinstalling the modules, and resetting the packager cache many times. Any thoughts? My package.json below.

```
{
  "name": "flexbox",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.43.3",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your dependency to this

```
{
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.43.3",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git#7edd9a7"
}
```

As discussed in this ticket: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/923